# Are there infinitely many primes that are a highly composite number $\pm 1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

I've looked at some highly composite numbers and realized that a lot of them are almost primes, i.e. differ only by $1$ to the next closest prime. Here's a short list (I made) of highly composite numbers and whether they are almost prime:
$$ 1 \text{, true $(+1)$} \\
2 \text{, true $(+1)$} \\
4 \text{, true $(\pm 1)$} \\
6 \text{, true $(\pm 1)$} \\
12 \text{, true $(\pm 1)$} \\
24 \text{, true $(-1)$} \\
36 \text{, true $(+1)$} \\
48 \text{, true $(-1)$} \\
60 \text{, true $(\pm 1)$} \\
120 \text{, false} \\
180 \text{, true $(\pm 1)$} \\
240 \text{, true $(\pm 1)$} \\
\dots $$

I've thought about it, and it's actually not so surprising that many highly composite numbers (which I've checked) are almost prime. Since $n \pm 1$ won't share any prime divisors with $n$, it's likely for $n \pm 1$ to be prime if $n$ has a high number of divisors.

But are there infinitely many highly composite numbers that are $\pm 1$ a prime? I don't know how I would prove something like this—I'm not even sure if this conjecture really holds.

Also, *if* there are infinitely many such numbers, do they get rarer? And at what rate?

Comment: Perhaps [Highly Composite Number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HighlyCompositeNumber.html) and [Prime Numbers Generated From
Highly Composite Numbers](https://www.parabola.unsw.edu.au/files/articles/2010-2019/volume-54-2018/issue-3/vol54_no3_4.pdf) provide some insight.

Comment: Related: http://bit-player.org/2021/does-having-prime-neighbors-make-you-more-composite

Comment: Such conjectures are usually out of reach , but chances are good for a prime since small prime factors can be ruled out , but the number of prime factors that can be ruled out is quite limited. On the other hand , the list of highly composite numbers should grow slow enough such that both kinds (-1 and +1) give infinite many primes.

Comment: Checking the known highly composite numbers is a good start to get a feeling whether this conjecture might be true.

Comment: I think , the official definition of "almost prime" is different from the here presented.

Comment: [here](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000006584660271) is a highly composite number constructed with the wikipedia-algorithm about super-highly-composite numbers with the choice $x=11.2$. If we call this number $N$ , then $N+1$ is a proven prime number.

Comment: [here](http://factordb.com/index.php?query=16979%23*293%23*53%23*23%23*2%5E15*3%5E8*5%5E4*7%5E2*11-1) a larger example ($x=14.0515$)